# Owin Security Keycloak LOGIN Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, owin, keycloak

I have a Web Forms project (.net 4.5) and im trying to include authentication with external servers with Owin.Security.Keycloak-3.

1: Downloaded and installed the nuggets packages.
2: Created the startup.cs class
3: I added the keys in Web.Config 
4: I added the login function

I have one problem, when you try to signin, Owin doesnt redirects you to the external login page.

I can force this with simple redirect but the Entity class is all the time empty, I want to Login, redirect to my project and get the User.Identity.Name .

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    const string persistentAuthType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType;
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType
        });
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType);
        app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Realm = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RealmId"],
            ClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"],
            KeycloakUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"],
            AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
            AllowUnsignedTokens = false,
            DisableIssuerSigningKeyValidation = false,
            DisableIssuerValidation = false,
            DisableAudienceValidation = false,
            TokenClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        });
```

Web.Config:

The keys are all OK, i have the same project in MVC and it works.

My function login:

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, ""));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, ""));            

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, claimsIdentity);
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Principal);
        HttpContext.Current.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Principal);
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(claimsIdentity);
```

Comment: Finally i didnt find the answer, so i use the mvc project like a tunnel to login and redirect to my web forms project.